# Assigning a Variable to the SELECT Statement query

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6

is there a way to assign a variable in CompanyName And AccountNo? can anyone help me. =)

```
      Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC11-PC\kim;Initial Catalog=Acounting;User ID=sa;Password=123")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select CompanyName, AccountNo From Company Inner Join Coa ON Company.CompanyID = Coa.CompanyID", con)
```

Comment: Use `Parameterized Queries`!

Comment: sorry but I don't know that yet. can you construct a parameterized queries?

Comment: What you want to get here? Do you want to fill data set or you want to send parameter as where?

Comment: I will actually use the query to populate a form.

Comment: This is not a VBA question, and not a VB6 question.  Tag whoring isn't acceptable practice here is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC11-PC\kim;Initial Catalog=Acounting;User ID=sa;Password=123")
  Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select CompanyName, AccountNo From Company Inner Join Coa ON Company.CompanyID = Coa.CompanyID", con)
  'Add this to your code
  Dim DA as data adapter
  Dim ds as new dataset
  DA.selecetcommand = cmd
  Da.fill(Ds)
```

Now you have all your data in your dataset you can use this dataset to fill grid or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Little Tutorial for you.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Example from site:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "select * from customers where city = @city"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtCity.Text.Trim)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select @CompanyName, @AccountNo From Company Inner Join Coa ON Company.CompanyID = Coa.CompanyID", con)
SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", companyVariable);
SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", accountVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign the results of the query into variables you can use in the program, you can use a DataAdapter and DataSet, something like this:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter ' or MySqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
...
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(ds)
```

Then ds.Tables(0).Rows will contain the results of the query.

For example, `ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("CompanyName")` will contain the first companyname from the query.

Answer (score -1):

If its giving multiple rows then you can fetch data into datatable then by using for loop you can get value in variables.

Comment: how can I get the CompanyName and AccountNo to a variable?